# How to integrate two cloud application in a fiori launch pad

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I have a requirement where i need to open two different cloud applications for example one hosted in SAP Cloud Platform and another hosted in IBM's cloud environment from the SAP Fiori Launch pad probably using two different tiles and the application should open within the same window.

SSO configurations are already in place where in the IBM system can be accessed when user logs into SAP cloud platform.

Regards,
Smith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating a tile, make sure you give the URL of app which is targeted to app in IBM system as a `Target URL` for the tile configurations under **Navigation**.

Make sure you enter protocol specifier like `http` or `https` without which this will fail.